# What is difference between Quantile function and standard normal quantile or probit function?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, stata

I'm reading about rank based inverse normal transformation. Basically it's applied to ranked random variable and transform it to normal distribution. I have problem in understanding the transformation function which called standard normal quantile function.
Can anybody explain me what is this function exactly ? 
Here is from paper :
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2921808/pdf/nihms-218012.pdf 
[image]

Comment: What is your exact question? The difference between a quantile function and what? Maybe your question becomes clearer if you give us some background of the real problem you want to solve.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: This is still very unclear. Please correct the title which is meaningless as is, indicate the source of this paper extract, and explain why you have difficulties with the quantile function that is the inverse of the cdf.

Comment: Basically I want to understand the difference between  quantile function and standard normal quantile function

Comment: The latter is a special case of the former: A quantile function is a general name for the quantile function of any distribution, the standard normal quantile function is the quantile function of a standard normal distribution.